# Invalid endpoint error after spring 15 upgrade

Tags: httprequest, httpresponse, spring15

I can't definitively say its spring 15 but it appears that some of our callouts to google maps (distance matrix api) for our managed package are failing in a customer's sandboxes (spring 15) that were previously working. None of our development sandboxes are in spring 15 yet so its hard to confirm. It's working fine in our test orgs that have test installs of the package (winter 15).

I'm getting an invalid endpoint error from this line:

> HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);

When I manually enter the `req` URL in the browser it works fine. Has anyone else experienced this or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the pipe delimiter wasn't being URLencoded which appears to have been the issue. This seems to cause an error in spring 15 orgs.