# Sandbox refresh

Tags: sandbox, release, sandbox-refresh, pre-release

Why do we need to refresh Sandbox before each Release? I read, previous Release(no preview), available if you after a specific date and latest Release(get the preview) if we request for refresh before a data. Can anyone throw some light and enlighten me!

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to SalesForces releases e.g. Sprint '15?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before SalesForce do a major release they will have a preview window where you can choose to preview the new release before it is rolled out. SalesForce do this by upgrading some Sandboxes, see the table below.

If you are on an instance that automatically gets upgraded to the preview release window then you may want to refresh so that you are excluded from the preview.

Alternatively, if you are on an instance that does not automatically get upgraded then you may want to refresh so that you are on an instance that is upgraded.

This table shows the instances for Spring '15

[image: Release Windows]

[Reference](http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2014/12/salesforce-spring-15-sandbox-preview-instructions.html?elq_mid=8329&elq_cid=5497863)

Answer (score 3):

You certainly do not have to refresh a sandbox for every release. Before every release salesforce will give you the opportunity to already, refresh your sandbox into the NEW, upcoming, release. This allows you to test new features or how your customizations combine with them.

This can only be done during a period of time, any sandboxes refreshed later (but before the production goes to the new version), will still be refreshed into the current release.

For instance:

```
 -----1:Winter----|----2:Sandbox Window----|--- 3:Winter-----|---4:Spring production Release------| repeat
```

1. Both your production org and refreshed sandboxes are on the winter release
2. Your production is on the winter release, but sandboxes created or refreshed now are on the spring release
3. Both your production org and refreshed sandboxes are on the winter release
4. Production goes to spring release, any new, existing or refreshed sandboxes too.

Answer (score 2):

Refreshing your sandbox before a release is not a requirement. It's a way of opting in or out of receiving the next release update in your sandbox *before* it is released for production.

As BarCotter noted in his post, Salesforce gives a table showing which instances will receive the release preview. They do this for every release (twice a year - spring & winter). If you're in a sandbox instance group that will receive the release preview but would prefer not to be upgraded, you have to refresh your sandbox in order to opt out of it. The reverse is also true.

I suggest joining the Success - Release Readiness Salesforce Chatter group: https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001okuCAA. There is a ton of information available in the group with discussions on what is available during which preview as well as instructions well in advance of each release for upgrading (or not) your sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers here ...

In my experience, having your active dev sandbox get upgraded to the pre-release version while you are trying to get day-to-day work done and fixes pushed to production can sometimes be exasperating as the pre-release sandboxes may have bugs wherein Apex code or other platform functionality stops working for days or weeks until repaired by the SFDC developers.

Just look through past SFSE posts [like this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63745/invalid-endpoint-error-after-spring-15-upgrade) to see that upgrading can be an 'adventure'.

That said, SFDC does an admirable job of keeping existing code functioning as they go through the release introduction process three times/year.

Obviously, if you want to take advantage of new features you need to upgrade.